# Can't compile freshly made extension library

Tags: acumatica

I cannot successfully compile an extension library that is freshly created using the Customization Project -> Extension Library -> Create New.

[image]

When compiling the freshly created extension library, I get the following error in the output, but no errors show in the error report:

> > 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Acumatica ERP\SilcotekDev\App_Data\Projects\ManufacturingTest\ManufacturingTest\Test.cs(6,7,6,9): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'PX' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I  have another custom extension library which had compiled successfully in the past, but today is not. Here is the full error list from that project's compilation:

[image]

I do have a custom DAC which I imported directly into the extension library, and I had compiled it before with that DAC added. Today it won't compile at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With update 3 of version 6.1 Acumatica has changed the target framework for its websites from 4.5.1 to 4.5.2. Unfortunately, the target version of the Addon.csproj VS project from the \App_Data\WebsiteSolution\Addon folder was not updated to .Net Framework 4.5.2 ***until update 9 of ver. 6.1 (build #6.10.0945)***. Because of the lower target version set for extension library VS project, VS cannot build the dll and therefore copy it to the Bin folder of your website.

There are 2 ways to resolve this type of an issue:

1. Change target framework version in VS for your extension library project:
   [image]
2. Open the Addon.csproj VS project in a text editor, like NotePad, and change the target framework to v4.5.2 as shown in the screenshot below (located in the \App_Data\WebsiteSolution\Addon folder inside your Acumatica website root folder). Create a new customization project inside Acumatica, then in Customization Manager create extension library for the new project
   [image]

Comment: I have seen this as Ruslan explained where the target .net version changed

Comment: That worked! Ruslan saves the day and quells the frustration once again! Thanks Ruslan!!!

Comment: My pleasure, Eric!

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things that could cause this problem.
1. is your program set up to read the PX namespace?
2. are you References setup the right way. You can always check by right clicking on the reference and selecting "Add reference"

Comment: Thanks for the response Metadata. I checked my references multiple times and saw that I had them. Ruslan resolved the issue in his response above.